# reading large file makes watchdog timer time-out elapses

Tags: c, file, fread, watchdog, lpc

I have created firmware program for LPC board. the time-out of watchdog timer is 2 seconds.I have a jpg file which i want to read and store in a buffer using freed() function.reading process is time-consuming so board resets while file reading is executed.

```
void func() {
 int num, NumBytes;
 static uint8_t acBuffer[0x1000];
 FILE *file ;
 // file contains large data 
 watchdog_reseter();
 num = fread(acBuffer, 1, NumBytes, file); // time-out elapses
 watchdog_reseter();
}
```

so i want to split file int to 2 or 3 files:

```
void func()
{
  int num, num1, num2, k;
  static uint8_t acBuffer[0x1000], buff[0x1000], buff2[0x1000];
  FILE *file, *file1, *file2 ; 
  /* task 1: file splits to file 1 and file2 */ 
  watchdog_reseter();
  num1 = fread(buff, 1, NumBytes/2, file1); // program resets
  watchdog_reseter();
  num2 = fread(buff2, 1, NumBytes/2, file2); // program resets
  watchdog_reseter(); 
  for(k=0; k<num1+num2, k++)
  {
    if(k<num1)
      acBuffer[k] = buff[k];
    else
      acBuffer[k] = buff2[k-num1];
  } 
}
```

help me to implement task1.

Comment: You could read the data into the buffer in smaller chunks until you have it all, allowing you to kick the dog more frequently. You can read it into one buffer, advancing the buffer location with each read (by the number of bytes read).

Comment: ... however if you have to wait on input in a blocking function, even a small data request might fail you, and a better strategy would be to interrogate the input until there is data available, while feeding the dog, and then read as much data as is ready.

Comment: Watchdog is usually serviced by another program. Do you have threads in the environment you are writing code for? Or use at least interrupt sources like timer.

Comment: @0andriy servicing a watchdog timer under interrupt is a very bad idea.

Comment: @WeatherVane, it depends, really. If you have embedded uniprocessor system the only choice you have is to use either interrupts to *indirectly* (meaning scheduling) service watchdog or split your state machine to pieces which are guaranteed to be small. For example, all OS functions can be interrupted by signal (they all implies regular check for the event) and timer interrupt handler just sends (sets bits) that signal. Do you have other ideas?

Comment: @0andriy the problem with servicing the watchdog under a timer interrupt is that if your code gets stuck in a loop, the watchdog will be kept happy. Might as well disable it.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I'm sorry, I didn't tell anything about servicing watchdog **under a timer interrupt**. You perhaps missed the point.

Comment: @MAB: Is a `fread(buff, 1, 512, file)` already too long to trigger the watchdog? If it is, you need to increase the watchdog timeout until you can always reliably read a small chunk. The size of the chunk depends on the hardware, but 512 is common on small/low-powered SBCs and microcontrollers. When that works, it is trivial to solve your issue with a simple loop, as outlined by Weather Vane in the first comment. There is no need to split the data to multiple files, or use more than one file handle.